# When building gem5.opt, I get 'ImportError: no module named six'

Tags: python, archlinux, gem5

I'm new to gem5. New even to computer architecture. I am trying to build the gem5.opt using `scons build/X86/gem5.opt` I get an import error for module six:

```
➜  gem5 scons build/RISCV/gem5.opt
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
ImportError: No module named six.py:
  File "/home/hari/gem5/SConstruct", line 102:
    from m5.util import compareVersions, readCommand
  File "/home/hari/gem5/src/python/m5/util/__init__.py", line 54:
    from .smartdict import SmartDict
  File "/home/hari/gem5/src/python/m5/util/smartdict.py", line 46:
    import six.py
```

- I have tried reinstalling python using pacman,
- Tried reinstalling the module six using pip,
- downgraded urlib3 version,
- recloned the repo too. (deleting the previous one ofcourse)

Answer (score 1):

Update: OP confirmed in comments that it was a Python 2 vs Python 3 problem, the python 2 package was:

```
python2-six
```

Previous answer: The problem is likely that it should be `import six` instead of `import six.py`.

The current upstream master does the right thing: https://github.com/gem5/gem5/blob/526a2fb619f5e5c2c2a7f19498a737571df189b7/src/python/m5/util/smartdict.py#L46

Also I tried `git log -p -G 'sys\.py'` to find a fixing commit, but no results, so I wonder: are you using mainline gem5 on a clean tree?

Please always provide your gem5 git SHA when asking gem5 questions.

Comment: I have used mercurial to download. Its hash is 256af4f35139. I actually added the six.py downloaded from python site and included it in the same directory as smartdict.py. I have the exact same error even with `import six` except the error is reflected accordingly. edit: thank you for replying so quickly

Comment: @LokanandaHari why are you using Mercurial, since the project moved to Git years ago? Why was there an import sys.py there? Had you made local changes and forgotten them?

Comment: Ok, so now I removed the mercurial stuff, and followed this [tutorial](http://learning.gem5.org/tutorial/presentations/learning%20gem5%20-%20part%201.pdf). I still get the error, except the last line says `import six`. SHA: b4c472945a6313e1ae1f4ba01477360c372dea6b

Comment: I followed the exact same procedure on my brother's pc which has ubuntu. It worked flawlessly. I think the issue has something to do with non-existent python-dev package for arch. Still, it shouldn't have a problem because apparently [arch ships headers right with the regular package](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=299628#p299628). If it doesnt work , then is it possible to do this in windows?

Comment: @LokanandaHari arch is much more likely to work than Windows :-) Can you do `import six` from a Python shell, independently of gem5? If not, get that working first. Have you installed six for the right version of Python? E.g. python3 vs python2 is pip3 vs pip in Ubuntu.

Comment: Installing python2-six solved the problem. Thanks. This was a very dumb problem. Sorry for all the fuss I have caused. Highly appreciate your attention.

Comment: No worries @LokanandaHari ! We are all learning here. I'll update the answer.