# gem5 "ImportError: No module named six" even though module six is installed

Tags: python, virtualenv, gem5

I'm trying to run a simple system in gem5[SHA: 332a9de33db603e0aefedae1e05134db4257ea3e
] from this [Link](http://learning.gem5.org/book/part1/simple_config.html). It shows following error:

> File "< string>", line 1, in < module>
>
> File "build/X86/python/importer.py", line 81, in load_module
>
> exec(code, mod.**dict**)
>
> File "build/X86/python/m5/**init**.py", line 46, in < module>
>
> from . import SimObject
>    File "build/X86/python/importer.py", line 81, in load_module
>
> exec(code, mod.**dict**)
>
> File "build/X86/python/m5/SimObject.py", line 43, in < module>
>
> from six import add_metaclass
>
> ImportError: No module named six

But I have module six installed and it is successfully used when I run [gem5 build](http://learning.gem5.org/book/part1/building.html). Also I cloud import six from other python IDE and command line without any issue.

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 and x86_64 architecture.

I have found similar [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56216358/when-building-gem5-opt-i-get-importerror-no-module-named-six) but here module six could not be detected during 
gem5.opt build. But my case gem5.opt build successfully found module six and complete operation. But do not found module six when trying to run simple.py system.

I have reinstalled module six, rebuild gem5.opt and even delete all files related to gem5 and clone it again. I have also tried this outside my virtual environment.

Comment: Can you double check with print statements that the same version of Python is used both for scons and the run? There have been quite a few related issues recently now that python3 support was fully added. Also ask on mailing list, people there have replied to related issues.

Comment: python 3.8 is the only python installed in my system (default ubuntu 20.04). So, I do not think this is an issue. Also, I do not how to explicitly check  python version for scons and the run (I'm new in gem5 and related software. Any link regarding this will be helpful)

Comment: Later I have install python 2.7 to run this,still same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is caused during gem5.opt build. 
As I was willing to use python3 from now on for gem5 as they announce python3 support. So, I use python3 for scons to gem5.opt build and it was successful. But when I tried to run first system script simple.py, import error occurs. My thought scons configuration file  miss-configure something in gem5.opt file during build while it uses python3.

I have rebuild gem5.opt using python2.7 and now problem is solved. Even I could use python3 to run "build/X86/gem5.opt config/tutorial/simple.py" and it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem and later solved it using

> sudo apt-get install python-six